# About the divergence of an infinite series.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Why is the series $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ not convergent, even though $$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}=0?$$

Comment: Because $a_n \rightarrow 0$ *does not* imply that $\sum a_n$ converges. The converse is true.

Comment: Because it's bigger than $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots$ (try to see how). It's one of the first surprising results one encounters in mathematics.

Comment: Thanx @Chrystomath.

Comment: This has surely been asked many times here.

Comment: because terms don'tget smaller fast enough, insted of $n$ it could be $\ln n$ or $\ln\ \ln n$, they all will make the terms go to zero but not fast enough. you can look at the integrals as well, similar story for them.

Answer (score 2):

$$
1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^n}=\\
=1+\frac{1}2+\left(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{5}+\cdots+\frac{1}{8}\right)+\cdots+\left(\frac{1}{2^{n-1}+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^n}\right)
$$
But
$$
\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\ge \frac{2}{4}=\frac{1}{2}, \\ 
\frac{1}{5}+\cdots+\frac{1}{8} \ge \frac{4}{8}=\frac{1}{2},
$$
and in general
$$
\frac{1}{2^{n-1}+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^n}\ge \frac{2^{n-1}}{2^n}=\frac{1}{2}
$$
and hence
$$
1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^n}\ge 1+\frac{n-1}{2}.
$$